In what practical use case would you choose to incorporate multilayered bearings i.e. bearing within a bearing?
Considering every aspect of engineering like durability, efficiency, cost vs service-life and all the possible mechanical issues,

Is there any practical advantage in using multilayered bearings? What use cases would make it a better choice?


They do look inspiring in terms of designing planetary gears but note that this question is not about gears. Here we are talking about bearings.

Detailed explanation about friction is welcome.

This has been asked before, but didnt find it in quick search. But yeah not much advantage, mostly detrimental.

Each bearing will have a max speed difference between outer race and inner...
